# Serialized log file

Tags: php, serialization

wondered if someone could point me in the right direction.

I have a log thats created when values are inserted into the database just as a backup, unfortunately, the host had to roll that back and I want to recover some of the data back.

The script writes it like this:

```
fwrite($handle, file_put_contents($target_path, serialize($array) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND));
```

The log file stores data like this:

```
514a:4:{s:10:"job_number";s:5:"00001";s:5:"title";s:10:"Job Spec 1";s:8:"Location";s:6:"City 1";}
502a:4:{s:10:"job_number";s:5:"00002";s:5:"title";s:10:"Job Spec 2";s:8:"Location";s:6:"City 2";}
```

I have tried to use

```
$recoveredData = file_get_contents('43532-12.txt');
$recoveredArray = unserialize($recoveredData);

print_r($recoveredArray);
```

But thats returning - Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset

I know it's probably me, i am under pressure to try and get this data back :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $recoveredData);
var_dump(unserialize($data));
```

I recommend using

```
//to safely serialize
$safe_string_to_store = base64_encode(serialize($multidimensional_array));

//to unserialize...
$array_restored_from_db = unserialize(base64_decode($encoded_serialized_string));
```

Because the serialize you are using will enter ", ', :, or ; in any of the array values and the serialization gets corrupted.

Comment: Thanks, for your help - it gave me an error back, 'The /e modifier is depreciated, use preg_replace_callback instead' - so I did try that, and then it errors with 'Requires argument 2, ''s:'.strlen('$2').':"$2";'', to be a valid callback' - really really appreciate your help though, I might just have to move on and forget the lost data, then implement your suggestion for the serialize part. - thanks again

Comment: One moment. I will get back to you

Comment: seems like it is lost :( but from now on use the suggestion above. Hope it will help you in the future

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Puya, appreciate it - not sure, do I mark yours as an answer now? - I can't imagine anyone picking up on this now?

Comment: No you don't have to mark it as answered just a one up for the future solution. I've tried everything to get the data restored but unfortunately the special characters have corrupted the serialization. You can try to set a bounty for your question maybe someone will have a solution (Y)

Comment: Thanks for spending time on it, I really do appreciate it, on with the Hosting providers to see if they have another closer backup. But yes, I am going to implement your solution going forward :)